# Git Extensions: No Windows Explorer shell on Windows 7 and all commands disabled in vs 2010 plugin?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2010, github, git-extensions

Just installed git extensions. All appeared to go well but if i right click in windows explorer there is no context sensitive menu for GIT as shown in the screenshots via the site. It seems to be missing. I have launched the Git Extensions applications and managed to clone a  repository so i know its working but the integration into the shell of windows exploer on windows 7 doesn't seem to be working

Also i instaled the plugin into vs 2010 and sure enough there is a menu called GIT

but all items are disabled apart from Settings and About Git Extensions...

So i can't clone a repository from here as it is disabled...

But the strange thing is if i create a new blank project then the git menu options all become Enabled,.....

Any ideas?

Really stuck on this, if someone can shine a light and give me a helping hand i would be very grateful

Answer (score 1):

I get the same behaviour. It is by design - I'm guessing. Just open gitextensions from the start menu. You have the option to clone a repository on the first page.

I would avoid any kind of source control integration with Visual Studio. It slows things down quite a bit. I know most people are used to mousing around. However, I much prefer dropping down to the git-bash and using aliases to get much more productivity. The only GUI I seem to use from time to time is Gitk with the --all option to visualize history.

Also, remember to shut down visual studio down every time you switch branches. And if you are using Resharper (as everyone should...) ensure your cache files are stored in the temp folder.

Comment: Hi, yes i managed to get it working opening gitextensions from the startmenu .... I am still not very used to bash (shell) of git... i am windows guy - je je . so I am also used to VS plugins.... I used visualsvn for example....

Its nice to hear you get the same design... but it seems to wrong to me... you can't clone (from vs) without having a project open.

Ok i suppose i will look into bash .. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know this sounds trivial, but did you make sure the Windows Explorer Shell integration option was selected in the installation process? because I had it working allright the first time around.
for the Visual Studio integartion, I noticed that the menu options only appear when a file is open.